# Concurrently push()ing to a shared queue with pthread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am practicing pthread.

In my original program, it `push`es to the shared queue an instance of a class called `request`, but I first at least want to make sure that I am pushing something to a shared queue.

It is a very simple code, but it just throws a lot of errors that I could not figure out the reason.

I guess it's probably the syntax, but whatever I tried it did not work.

Do you see why it is not working?

Following is the code I have been trying.

```
extern "C" {
    #include<pthread.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
}
#include<queue>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class request {
 public:
    string req;
    request(string s) : req(s) {}

};

int n;
queue<request> q;
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void * putToQueue(string);

int main ( void ) {
    pthread_t t1, t2;

    request* ff = new request("First");
    request* trd = new request("Third");

    int result1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &putToQueue, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&ff));
    if (result1 != 0) cout << "error 1" << endl;
    int result2 = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &putToQueue, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&trd));
    if (result2 != 0) cout << "error 2" << endl;

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    for(int i=0; i<q.size(); ++i) {
        cout << q.front().req << " is in queue" << endl;
        q.pop();
        --n;
    }

    return 0;
}

void * putToQueue(void* elem) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);

    q.push(reinterpret_cast<request>(elem));
    ++n;

    cout << n << " items are in the queue." << endl;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I guess it's probably the syntax", do you even know what a syntax error is? Did you start by writing a single-threaded program that puts strings in a queue? It looks like you barely know what C++ is, and already wants to jump to multithreaded programming.

Comment: sorry, but that is not true. I am a decent C++ programmer, but just about pthread I know not much.

Comment: I don't believe a decent C++ programmer would write `string* msg1 = "First";`.

Comment: "I am practicing pthread." That's your mistake right there. You should almost certainly use the threading primitives included in C++11 instead. Mostly similar ideas, but generally cleaner and more portable.

Comment: Sorry. The code changed a lot from my original code, as I tried everything I could think of, and it was something like const char* msg1 = (some string).c_str();

Comment: If you don't show the real code that's giving you problems, and not even more details on the supposed error you are getting, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: Okay. The problem is in reinterpret_cast<void*>(&msg1). What is wrong with this? I can never figure out. I tried everything with msg1

Comment: why are you casting the address of a pointer to a pointer? Get rid of the & in the `reinterpret_cast` maybe? And on the other side, you're casting it to an object, but never dereferencing it. cast to request*

Comment: Your prototype for `void * putToQueue(string);` isn't a valid pthread-proc. Having to slam a `reinterpret_cast` around it is a sure-fire indication thats wrong. And it doesn't match the implementation below `main()` anyway. You're taking the addresses of local variables that point to dynamic allocations rather than passing the pointers themselves, indicating an apparent misunderstanding of how a void* automatic cast works. And your leaking memory in the only two dynamic allocations made in this entire code base.

Comment: ...continued And the reinterpret-cast in the the thread proc is also wrong.

Comment: Thank you all for your critiques. I saw how unprepared I was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below comments on everything that had to be changed. I would write up a detailed description of *why* they had to change, but I hope the code speaks for itself. It *still* isn't bullet-proof. There are plenty of things that could be done differently or better (exception handling for failed `new`, etc) but at least it compiles, runs, and doesn't leak memory.

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

// MINOR: param should be a const-ref
class request {
public:
    string req;
    request(const string& s) : req(s) {}
};

int n;
queue<request> q;
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


// FIXED: made protoype a proper pthread-proc signature
void * putToQueue(void*);

int main ( void )
{
    pthread_t t1, t2;

    // FIXED: made thread param the actual dynamic allocation address
    int result1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &putToQueue, new request("First"));
    if (result1 != 0) cout << "error 1" << endl;

    // FIXED: made thread param the actual dynamic allocation address
    int result2 = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &putToQueue, new request("Third"));
    if (result2 != 0) cout << "error 2" << endl;

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    // FIXED: was skipping elements because the queue size was shrinking
    //  with each pop in the while-body.
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        cout << q.front().req << " WAS in queue" << endl;
        q.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}

// FIXED: pretty much a near-total-rewrite
void* putToQueue(void* elem)
{
    request *req = static_cast<request*>(elem);
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mut) == 0)
    {
        q.push(*req);
        cout << ++n << " items are in the queue." << endl;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    }
    delete req; // FIXED: squelched memory leak
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (yours *may* vary)

```
1 items are in the queue.
2 items are in the queue.
Third WAS in queue
First WAS in queue
```

Comment: @user2418202 You're welcome. I hope it helped a little. And seriously, learn about pthreads, then look at the [C++11 threading primitives](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) and [C++11 atomic primitives](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic). They're absolutely *outstanding* and make stuff like this a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment, I'd advise skipping direct use of pthreads, and use the C++11 threading primitives instead. I'd start with a simple protected queue class:

```
template <class T, template<class, class> class Container=std::deque>
class p_q {
    typedef typename Container<T, std::allocator<T>> container;
    typedef typename container::iterator iterator;

    container data;
    std::mutex m;
public:
    void push(T a) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
        data.emplace_back(a);
    }
    iterator begin() { return data.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return data.end(); }
    // omitting front() and pop() for now, because they're not used in this code
};
```

Using this, the main-stream of the code stays *nearly* as simple and clean as single-threaded code, something like this:

```
int main() {
    p_q<std::string> q;

    auto pusher = [&q](std::string const& a) { q.push(a); };

    std::thread t1{ pusher, "First" };
    std::thread t2{ pusher, "Second" };

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    for (auto s : q)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

As it stands right now, this is a multiple-producer, single-consumer queue. Further, it depends on the fact that the producers are no longer running when the consuming is happening. That's true in this case, but wouldn't/won't always be. When it's not the case, you'll need a (marginally) more complex queue that does locking as it reads/pops from the queue, not just when writing to it.